# Observable subscription remains active after component has been destroyed

Tags: angular

One of my components subscribes to router events like so:

```
    this.navigationSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
      // If it is a NavigationEnd event re-initalise the component
      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        let p = e as NavigationEnd;
          console.log(p.urlAfterRedirects);
        console.log("im being called from NavigationEnd");
        this.ngOnInit();
      }
    });
   }
```

I use this code to reload the component when the user navigates to the component a second time via a button. While debugging a problem i noticed that when i navigate to another component this piece of code still remains active even though the component that its part of is not. Can someone explain why and how this code stays active even though the component itself is no longer there? Shouldn't the code cause an error when it can no longer reach `this.ngOnInit()` ?

I can solve this problem by unsubscribing to it in the onDestroy method but i would really like to know how the code is able to stay active when the component is no longer there, and why `this.ngOnInit()` doesn't throw an error since the component is not active.

Comment: Save your subscription in an variable and unsubscribe() onDestroy

Comment: i know, thats why i'm doing already. But i am relatively new to Angular and i was wondering if someone could explain to me why the subscription persists even after the component has been destroyed (when i dont use ngDestroy to undsubscribe that is)

Comment: Check if you really cancelled ALL your subscriptions. Maybe you are generating several subscriptions which arent saved in any variables so they kind of exist in the nirvana and the garbage collector / ngDestroy LifeCycle Hook cannot destroy the component

Comment: subscriptions don't go to Nirvana, they go to the Matrix. go ask Neo ;) Anyway, I know that i have to cancel each subscription with ngOnDestroy but i was wondering why it is that the subscription persists if you don't unsubscribe.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, all subscriptions remain active after the component is destroyed.

It is one of the big pains of Angular IMO.

However, there are some exceptions to this rule:

- this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe - automatically unsubscribes
- this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe - automatically unsubscribes
- any http subscriptions - these will emit once and then complete, so no need to unsub
- async pipes unsub automatically

For everything else you need to unsub manually. There are various ways of doing this but here is the RxJs recommended approach:

```
private unsubscribe$ = new Subject()

this.someobservable.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
).subscribe( .... )

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.unsubscribe$.next()
  this.unsubscribe$.complete()
}
```

Comment: right now i am using just the `.unsubscribe()` method, why should i use `.next()` isn't that ment to push a value to all the components that are subscribed to the same observable/behaviorsubject? and what does `complete()` do exactly?

Comment: takeUntil will take values until the subject completes. When the subject completes all observables using the takeUntil pipe will complete also. You don't have to unsub each observable manually - here's an article from the RxJs lead dev who recommends this approach - https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: see link in previous comment - also, when an observable or subject completes, it never emits again, the complete method is called (if one is provided) and then it is as dead as a dodo

Comment: i know, but it is undesirable to have all subscriptions in all other components/services be ended as well. This should only be done when the program itself ends.

Comment: it doesnt kill all subscriptions in all other components/services - only those in this component that use takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)

Comment: they all share the same BehaviorSubject that is instantiated in one service, they all listen in on that one behaviorsubject, so your approach doesn't work for this scenario.

Answer (score 5):

A physical world example, and how I understand subscriptions: if I subscribe to a newspaper to my street address, and my house gets destroyed by (insert bad scenario), I still have to cancel the subscription, otherwise the newspapers will pile up on the burned heap of what used to be my home.

Comment: and news papers cost money, and money is finite kind of like memory space is finite right?

Comment: Technically, money is not finite central banks because central banks do not even need to print it on physical paper to create it. However, you as an individual are in possession of a finite amount of money.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain why and how this code stays active even though the
>   component itself is no longer there?

Although the component is "no longer there", this only means that the pointer to the `Subscription` instance stored in it is gone, but the subscription is still 'active', and most likely tracked by the `router.events` stream, explaining why the GC cant simply remove the instance from memory.

> Shouldn't the code cause an error when it can no longer reach
>   this.ngOnInit() ?

Most likely related to the first point, as the GC cant release the component instance.

Comment: ok so the component instance doesn't get destroyed because the subscription is still referencing to part of it? (the `this.ngOnInit()` part)

Comment: Also, what happens when i completely stop the web application by surfing to another website for example. Will the subscription then be garbage collected or will it continue to use up memory?